# Ansible: Best way to detect if a certificate is already installed in the Certificate Store

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, certificate, ansible

While waiting on [the new certificate module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1374), we are installing certificates in the following way:

`win_shell: Import-PfxCertificate -filepath "{{ certificatePath }}" -certStorelocation cert:\\localmachine\\My -password $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "{{ organization_key }}")`

This works fine, but I have not found any good way to skip the task if the certificate is already installed. I know that you can run `SET-LOCATION CERT:\LOCALMACHINE`, which provides access to the certificate store as a filesystem, but it is possible to do something like `creates=cert:\localmachine\path\to\my\cert`?

What is the best strategy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple: 
`creates=Cert:\\LOCALMACHINE\\My\\{{ CertificateThumbprint }}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Test-Path` cmdlet also works with the certificate provider:

```
if (Test-Path cert:\localmachine\path\to\my\cert)
{
}
```